# broadcast messages to other sockets?

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

I am trying to make chat application with nodejs socket.io

While reading socket.io doc,

> This makes it easy to broadcast messages to other sockets:
>
> ```
> io.on('connection', function(socket){
>   socket.on('say to someone', function(id, msg){
>     socket.broadcast.to(id).emit('my message', msg);
>   });
> });
> ```

I can understand that 'say to someone' is an event, and second arguments is an event-handler function.

But what I cannot understand perfectly is that I thought that when the client-side emits the event, it sends the object with that event.

```
//client-side
socket.emit('some event', {id: "some_id", msg: "some_msg"})

//server-side
socket.on('some event', function(data){
  socket.broadcast.to(data.id).emit('my message', data.msg);
});
```

But as you can see the code in doc above,

it receives two arguments, id and msg.

how can that be possible?

some explanation would really be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the function parameters in the callback for the `say to someone` event:

```
io.on('connection', function(socket){
  socket.on('say to someone', function(id, msg){
    socket.broadcast.to(id).emit('my message', msg);
  });
});
```

Notice how they line up with with the object properties being passed for the event on the client side?

(id -> id, msg -> msg)

```
//client-side
socket.emit('some event', {id: "some_id", msg: "some_msg"})
```

The object is being deconstructed and it's properties being passed to the callback function as it's parameters.